# Are there more branches to Calculus other than differentiation and integration?

Tags: calculus

Wikipedia states that Calculus has two major branches, differential calculus and integral calculus.

Are there other minor branches ?

I am not an expert of Calculus and cannot find an answer anywhere.

Comment: I'm certainly no expert either, but I don't think it would be an unfair characterization to say that calculus is the prelude to analysis. Analysis itself splits into several subfields, such as functional analysis, numerical analysis, complex analysis, etc.

Comment: I’m not even sure that I would agree with Wikipedia on this issue. Remember this: “There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,/ Than are dreamt of in your philosophy”. And I would say that this applies to mathematics just as well as to philosophy.

Comment: differential equations and differential geometry use many ideas from calculus but are by no means, "minor branches".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could say that Calculus has some "minor branches."

One "minor branch" in most first-year Calculus textbooks is infinite series. This topic is related to both differentiation and integration but belongs to neither. This is often at the end of the textbook, not always reached during the class lessons.